# How do I set up an ABLE Account

Tags: united-states, trusts

It's a disability account. I'm disabled and need help with money. I need help setting up an able bank account

Comment: There called able accounts that banks allow if your disability starts before 26 years old

Comment: Please add a state tag.

Comment: I'd call a bank and ask them.

Comment: This link might help: http://www.ablenrc.org/select-a-state-program/

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it depends on your state government to allow them (most do). I would start by googling “[your state name] able account”.

I did so for Washington state (just an example, since you don’t say where you live) and found washingtonstateable.com, which has a link to open an account.

(Edit) Or just use the link posted in a comment above to find your state’s program: http://www.ablenrc.org/select-a-state-program/